# Navigating Directories in Python

Tags: python, directory, ipython

Im trying to navigate directories in python like this, and for some reason its telling me that 
`IOError: File ../Harvard%20Stats%20Course%20Data%20Files/diamonds.csv` does not exist. The file does exist, however, one folder out, and then in the Harvard Stats Course Data Files folder.

```
diamond_data = pd.read_csv('../Harvard Stats Course Data Files/diamonds.csv',
sep = ',', index_col=0)`
```

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: I suggest double-checking that a file with that exact name actually does exist in that exact location. Keep checking until you determine the file's actual name and location.

Answer (score 1):

At the IPython prompt, type [`pwd`](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/2/api/generated/IPython.core.magics.osm.html#IPython.core.magics.osm.OSMagics.pwd). That will show you the current working directory. Perhaps it is not the directory you think it is. You can change the current workding directory by typing [`cd /path/to/dir`](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/2/api/generated/IPython.core.magics.osm.html#IPython.core.magics.osm.OSMagics.cd) at the IPython prompt.

Alternatively, you could simply supply an absolute path to the CSV file.

Answer (score 0):

Using `../` like that will be relative to wherever you're running the program from. Try to change into the directory of the .py file and run it again.